# GWTAI applet integration in GWT problem

Tags: java, gwt, applet

I'm working with [gwtai](http://code.google.com/p/gwtai/) to integrate a java applet into my gwt - project. Basic communication from my main application to the applet (such as invoking simple methods that return int or boolean values) works.

But the main reason why I need to integrate this applet is, that I need it to connect to another server and receive a answer and pass it to my gwt-application.

So there's one basic method in the applet:

```
public String SendAndReceive(String host, int sendPort, int receivePort, String query)
```

that connects to the server, receives an answer and returns this answer as a string.

When I now try to invoke this method like this:

```
applet.SendAndReceive("0.0.0.0", 9099, 2000, "show streams;");
```

I constantly run into following error (full error message at the end):

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (String): Error calling method on NPObject! [plugin exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission * read,write)]
```

I couldn't find a solution (for gwtai is a quite uncommon topic), what I found out (and what the Exception let's one assume) is, that there's a security problem - maybe because I'm connecting to another server. I also read something about browser's Single Origin Policy, what would point in the same direction...up to now I have never worked with java applets.

So if someone has a solution or a hint I would be very thankful. If more code is helpful I can give.

Thanks,

Andy

---

the full error message:

21:03:49.864 [ERROR] [follovizergwt] Unable to load module entry point class follovizer.gwt.client.FolloVizerGWT (see associated exception for details)
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (String): Error calling method on NPObject! [plugin exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission * read,write)].
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:195)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at follovizer.gwt.client.AnduINAppletImpl.SendAndReceive(AnduINAppletImpl.java)
    at follovizer.gwt.client.FolloVizerGWT.createLayout(FolloVizerGWT.java:92)
    at follovizer.gwt.client.FolloVizerGWT.onModuleLoad(FolloVizerGWT.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:369)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:185)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:380)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other browser plugins, Java Applets have [security restrictions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html). Notably, they can only make network connections to the host they came from. You cannot use applets to connect to arbitrary servers.

Communicating with other servers is a fairly common requirement, and there are several ways to get around it. Common solutions are Flash + Crossdomain.xml and JSONP. There are other solutions as well, just do a google search for all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If your Java applet needs to make a cross-domain request then it will need to be signed. By default the Java sandbox doesn't allow applets to fetch pages that reside in a domain different than that from which the applet originated.